# woocommerce variable product "add to cart" says "Please select some product options before adding this product to your cart."

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, elementor, wordpress-theme-astra

I have created a variable product with four different quantities, but on the front end, while adding it to the cart, a pop-up says, "Please select some product options before adding this product to your cart."

I have tried downgrading and changing the theme to default; but nothing worked as expected.
Anyone can help.

URL: Please select some product options before adding this product to your cart.

[VIEW PRODUCT in URL](https://ifsco.in/product/cardamom/)

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that a variation is never selected as you have an error in 'add-to-cart-variation.js' on line 785 that prevents selection. the error reports as 'caught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'textContent')'

There are also a few jQuery related issues. I would check where this 'add-to-cart-variation.js' is being loaded and make sure it loads AFTER jQuery as if its dependent it may be failing as jQuery is not loaded before it. Next I would, as a temporary measure, Load in your head tags a 'const $ = jQuery;' script to see if its the common WP jquery is undefined issue.

Comment: i havnt enough knowledge about it "Load in your head tags a 'const $ = jQuery;' " how can i do it ? file location ?